# How do I keep track of the index of QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem added into my graphicsscene

Tags: c++, qt

I added several rectangles into QGraphicssene using QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem. How do I keep track of the rectangles ID/ index so that I can delete the correct rect when user selects and press delete button. Besides deleting it from the graphisscene, I also need to delete the particular rect data in my QList. Below is the code where I add my rect into the graphicsscene.

```
QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem *i = m_pCamImageScene->addRect(General::instance()->maskingRect);
i->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
i->setBrush(brush);
i->setPen(pen);
```

I had tried creating an unordered_map to store the QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem  and its index but got errors stating that unordered_map does not have overloaded function during insert.

std::unordered_map mGraphicsShapeItems;

```
mGraphicsShapeItems.insert(i, 1);
```

I expect to get the index of the rect and able to delete it from the graphicsscene and also from my QList

Comment: Why can't you refer to a `QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem` by a pointer to it?

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm still very new to QT. Can you elaborate more about your reply?

Comment: Please show us the code where you define and use `mGraphicsShapeItems`.

Comment: I had added the code in my above post
    
    QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem *i = m_pCamImageScene->addRect(General::instance()->maskingRect);
i->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
i->setBrush(brush);
i->setPen(pen);

Comment: Please show us the code where you *define* and *use* **the std::unordered_map `mGraphicsShapeItems`**. (All places, not only the insert.)

Comment: CCamImageScene* m_pCamImageScene; // is a QGraphicsScene

QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem *i = m_pCamImageScene->addRect(General::instance()->maskingRect);
 i->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
 i->setBrush(brush);
 i->setPen(pen);

std::unordered_map<QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem*, int> mGraphicsShapeItems;
mGraphicsShapeItems.insert(i, 1);